# Adding to a variable does not work correctly with recursive call in Java

Tags: java

I was implementing a bridge finding algorithm on a graph when I stumbled upon a bug where my recursive calls don't sum correctly.

If you look at my recursive calls in the function "root()", the one marked "DOES WORK" resolves the "cnt" of the node indexed at 2 as 2 (the correct answer) after terminating, while the one that doesn't work correctly makes "cnt" 4. I've used the debugger to try to pinpoint the problem, but the issue is that I don't think there is any problem with my code. At one point, the recursive call returns 2, and the value of "cnt" for node 2 should be -1, but after adding with the incorrect block of code, "cnt" becomes 2 instead of 1.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm not sure if it's an error with java, my IDE, or something on my part.

```
public class BridgeFind {
    int N;
    Node[] dfsTree;
    boolean[] visited;
    void init() {
        dfsTree = new Node[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            dfsTree[i] = new Node();
        }
        visited = new boolean[N];
    }
    int root(int n, int p, int d) {
        visited[n] = true;
        dfsTree[n].d = d;
        for (int ch : dfsTree[n].adj) {
            if (ch != p) {
                if (!visited[ch]) {
                    //DOES NOT WORK
                    dfsTree[n].cnt += root(ch, n, d+1);

                    //DOES WORK
                    int val = root(ch, n, d+1);
                    dfsTree[n].cnt += val;

                } else if (dfsTree[n].d > dfsTree[ch].d){
                    dfsTree[n].cnt++;
                    dfsTree[ch].cnt--;
                }
            }
        }
        return dfsTree[n].cnt;
    }
    static class Node {
        ArrayList<Integer> adj = new ArrayList<>();
        int cnt = 0;
        int d;
    }
    void add(int a, int b) {
        a--;
        b--;
        dfsTree[a].adj.add(b);
        dfsTree[b].adj.add(a);
    }
    void solve() {
        N = 12;
        init();
       add(1, 3);
       add(5, 3);
       add(7, 5);
       add(6, 3);
       add(6, 2);
       add(2, 8);
       add(2, 4);
       add(4, 10);
       add(1, 9);
       add(9, 11);
       add(11, 12);
       add(9, 12);
       add(1, 6);
       add(1, 5);
       add(3, 7);
       add(3, 8);
       root(0, 0, 0);
       visited = new boolean[N];
       System.out.println(dfsTree[2].cnt);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BridgeFind next = new BridgeFind();
        next.solve();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the two code snippets look superficially similar, they aren't actually doing the same thing at all.

This block is first evaluating `root(ch, n, d+1)` (which modifies `dfsTree[n].cnt`), and then adding the returned value to the new value of `dfsTree[n].cnt`.

```
int val = root(ch, n, d+1);
dfsTree[n].cnt += val;
```

On the other hand, this line is first capturing the value of `dfsTree[n].cnt`, then evaluating `root(ch, n, d+1)` (which modifies `dfsTree[n].cnt`), the adding the returned value to the original value of `dfsTree[n].cnt` and storing it, which overwrites the modifications that took place inside the call to `root(ch, n, d+1)`.

```
dfsTree[n].cnt += root(ch, n, d+1);
```

EDIT

If you want a single line solution that doesn't rely on a temp variable, you can force the order of evaluation by writing out a standard assignment.  `x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y`, but if you need `y` to be evaluated first, you can simply write it out as `x = y + x`.

e.g.

```
dfsTree[n].cnt = root(ch, n, d+1) + dfsTree[n].cnt;
```

results in a program output of `2`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense actually. To make sure my understanding is correct, if I wrote dfsTree[n] = root(ch, n, d+1) + dfsTree[n] then the code would work as intended because root() is evaluated first?

Comment: Correct.  I've updated my answer to make it more explicit.